# $d_1, d_2$ are metrics on $X$; $(X,d_1)$ is complete. Let $i:(X,d_1)\to(X,d_2)$ be continuous and $i^{-1}$ unif. cont. Show $(X,d_2)$ is complete.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

This is a problem on an old preliminary exam in Analysis I'm working through. The problem initially looked easy to me; my plan is to show that for any $\{x_n\}$ Cauchy in $(X,d_2)$, we have that $\{i^{-1}(x_n)\}$ is Cauchy in $(X,d_1)$, therefore convergent to some $x\in X$, and therefore by the continuity of $i$ we have that $x_n\xrightarrow{d_2}x$.

The problem I run into is that I can't quite see how to show that $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy in $(X,d_1)$. I don't see how the uniform continuity of $i^{-1}$ comes into play, either. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Every uniformly continuous function sends Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences. Prove that with the definition of uniform continuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $(x_n)$ is Cauchy in $d_2$. For any $\delta > 0$ : $d_2(x_n,x_m) < \delta$ for $n,m$ large enough. By uniform continuity of $i^{-1}$ it follows that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy in $d_1$, hence convergent.

To be very precise: Let $\epsilon > 0$ and $\delta > 0$ such that $d_2(x,y) < \delta$ implies that $d_1(i^{-1}(x),i^{-1}(y)) = d_1(x,y) < \epsilon$ . Then, there exists an $N$ with $n,m \geq N$ implies $d_2(x_n,x_m) < \delta$ and hence $d_1(x_n,x_m) < \epsilon$ for $n,m \geq N$. Since this can be done for every $\epsilon > 0$ it follows that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy in $d_1$.

Comment: I guess my difficulty is in seeing why uniform continuity implies that $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy in $d_1$.

Comment: Here's a go: since $i^{-1}$ is u.c., we have that for all $\epsilon>0$, $\exists \delta>0$ such that $d_1(i^{-1}(z),i^{-1}(y))<\epsilon$ for all $z,y$ such that $d_2(z,y)<\delta$. Since $x_n\xrightarrow{d_2}x$, we have that for high enough $N$, $d_2(x_n,x_m)<\delta$ for all $m,n>N$. Thus $d_1(i^{-1}(x_n),i^{-1}(x_m))<\epsilon$. Thus Cauchy.

Comment: Almost correct, but you don't assume that $x_n \to x$ in $d_2$. You just pick a Cauchy sequence in $(X,d_2)$ and then prove that it is also Cauchy in $(X,d_1)$ and hence convergent.